# How to get the list of employees according to mat-radio-button click [active / inactive / all]

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api, angular-material, angular7

I have a list of employee's including (active, inactive employee's) displayed in dashboard. So now I want to display by default only active employee's list. If I click on Inactive radio button, then it should display only Inactive list. All means all the list of employee's **active** and **inactive**.

## HTML page

````
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 mb-4 col-full" widget>
    <div class="silk-card border-success pb-0">
      <div class="silk-card-title d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg mx-1"></i>Employees List</h4>
        <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="isActive" (ngModelChange)="getUsersDataOfType($event)">
          <mat-radio-button [value]="1"><b>Active</b></mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button [value]="0"><b>Inactive</b></mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button [value]="2"><b>All</b></mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </div>
      <div class="silk-card-content widget-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort *ngIf="isActive">

              <ng-container matColumnDef="employeeId">
                <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Employee ID
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matCellDef="let element">
                  <b>{{element.actualEmployeeCode}}</b></mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
                <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassMedium'" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassMedium'" *matCellDef="let element">
                  <b>{{element.firstname | titlecase }} {{element.lastname | titlecase }}</b></mat-cell>
              </ng-container>
              <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Name</mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell style="text-align: center;" *matCellDef="let element">{{element.lastname}}</mat-cell>
                          </ng-container> -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="emailaddress">
                <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassLarge'" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassLarge'" *matCellDef="let element">{{element.emailaddress}}
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>
              <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="deptname">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Department</mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.deptname}}</mat-cell>
                          </ng-container> -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="rolename">
                <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Role
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matCellDef="let element">{{element.rolename}}</mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matCellDef="let element">
                  <span *ngIf="element.isactive == 1" style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">Active</span>
                  <span *ngIf="element.isactive == 0" style="color: #E83F6F; font-weight: bold;">Inactive</span>
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="length_service">
                  <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Length of Service</mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.length_service }}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container> -->

              <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell [ngClass]="'customWidthClassSmall'" *matCellDef="let row">
                  <button mat-icon-button>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/hr/editemployee',row.user_id]">
                      <mat-icon>mode_edit</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                  </button>
                  <!-- <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="open(row)">
                              <a [routerLink]="['/hr/editemployee',row.user_id]"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></a>  
                              </button> -->
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
                <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="4">
                  Loading data...
                </mat-footer-cell>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
                <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="4">
                  No data.
                </mat-footer-cell>
              </ng-container>
              <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
              <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
              <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [hidden]="(listData!=null)"></mat-footer-row>
              <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [hidden]="!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)">
              </mat-footer-row>
            </mat-table>
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[1,5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```





#TS file#

    getUsersDataOfType(value) {
    this.ser.Getmethod('api/Employee1/GetEmploymees').subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      if (value == 1) {
        console.log('Value : ' + value);
        $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log('JQUERY');
          this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
          this.listData.sort = this.sort;
          this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
      } else if (value == 0) {
        console.log('Value : ' + value);
        $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log('JQUERY');
          this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
          this.listData.sort = this.sort;
          this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
      } else if (value == 2) {
        console.log('Value : ' + value);
        $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log('JQUERY');
          this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
          this.listData.sort = this.sort;
          this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.errormethod(error);
      });
  }


  [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nxD5.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call Api evenry time as user ask for active or inactive emps, just filter the data based on the events and show the results
get all the Employees in ngOnInit() method,

```
ngOnInit(){
 //api get all employees
this.data = result;
this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
this.listData.sort = this.sort;
this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
}

getUsersDataOfType(value) {
var filteredData = [];
// filter this.data based on the value; and assign result to filteredData array
this.listData.data = filteredData;
}
```

and you don't need to use $(document).ready(function () {} function with angular.

Comment: filtering only I'm unable to do based on active or inactive. Can you help me how to filter the data.

Comment: how do you know an employee is acvite or Inactive ? can you add one object of an employee ?

Comment: Yes we will have an option while creating an employee data. While creating the employee will be in active mode. If he left the company or some other cases we have an option to edit the field from active to inactive mode.

Comment: Thanks for the filtering suggestion I got it. It work's fine.